# TypeError: descriptor 'isoformat' for 'datetime.date' objects doesn't apply to a 'str' object

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datetime

I'm doing a university project in Python, I need to import from a `JSON` a string in the format of `datetime.date` that would be `YYYY-MM-DD`, I was testing in a short program and I had no problems, but when entering in my general code it gave me this error

```py
dt = date.isoformat(info["start_date"])
```

Answer (score 2):

This error message (admittedly not a very helpful one) implies you've tried to call on the *type* `datetime.date` directly, rather than an instance of it.

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> date.isoformat("something")
TypeError: descriptor 'isoformat' for 'datetime.date' objects doesn't apply to a 'str' object
```

Instead it expects to be called as a method, without any arguments:

```
>>> date.today().isoformat()
'2022-06-05'
```

However, after reading your question it looks like you actually want to go the *other* way, parsing from a string into a date instance:

```
>>> date.fromisoformat("2022-06-05")
datetime.date(2022, 6, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to convert a string date to string date again which does not makes sense.

`datetime.isoformat()` takes a `date` as an argument, and converts it into a datetime object.

For example, let's consider this.

```py
print(datetime.date.isoformat(datetime.now()))
>>> 2022-06-05
```

If you try to print `datetime.now()` you will see it returns a `date` instead of a string. So in above, `.isoformat` takes a date as an argument, then converts it into an `iso` string

So if you pass a string an argument here, code will surely crash, because it is expecting a date instead.

You need to use `.fromisoformat()` to convert strings to dates.

To give you an example, this code prints current date in every computer.

```py
import datetime
today_in_iso_format = datetime.date.isoformat(datetime.datetime.now()) 
print(datetime.date.fromisoformat(today_in_iso_format))
```